# How to adjust button text to make it fit on top botton and sides

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a nav bar list with links, the last item is a button. I displayed them using flex box, but when it's rendered the button text is not flush/even against the top, so it will display uneven.

Here's a photo:

[image]

As you can see the `FOO BAR` is not even with the items to the left.

Here's the HTML:

```
 <nav className={styles.PrivateHeaderNav}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h5>LOGO HERE</h5>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink activeClassName={styles.NavLink__active} to="/profile">
            FOO
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink activeClassName={styles.NavLink__active} to="/game_groups">
            FOO
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink activeClassName={styles.NavLink__active} to="/feed">
            FOO
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => logOutCurrentUser()}>
            FOO BAR
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.PrivateHeaderNav {
  background-color: #252334;
  color: #ff7376;
  font-size: 20px;

  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 0.5em 0.1em;

    li {
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        &:visited {
          color: #ff7376;
        }
        &.NavLink__active {
          color: #ffe880;
        }
      }

      button {
        padding: 0px;
        white-space: normal;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        color: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a photo with a border so I can see it clearly.

[image]

---

Is there a `inner padding btn` something on CSS that I can use to remove the padding? or margin? I don't even know if there's such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.privateHeaderNav {
    background-color: #252334;
    color: #ff7376;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.privateHeaderNav ul {
    /* Changing justify-content: space-around to make beautiful auto spacing between the li, in this case no need for the left-right padding (Check @media below), and finally align items to fit perfectly centered*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around; /*Changed*/
    padding: 0.5em 0; /*Changed*/
    align-items: center; /*Added*/
}
.privateHeaderNav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.privateHeaderNav ul li a:visited {
    color: #ff7376;
}
.privateHeaderNav ul li a.NavLink__active {
    color: #ffe880;
}
.privateHeaderNav ul li button {
    /*Align center the button content to match the a tag(links) */
    padding: 0px;
    white-space: normal;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    display: flex; /*Added*/
    justify-content: center; /*Added*/
    align-items: center; /*Added*/
}


/*Add @media to remove the beautiful space we added between the li, basicly we're stretching the list 100%*/
@media(max-width:576px){
    .privateHeaderNav ul {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    /*Since we removed the space, we have to add padding left-right we removed previously*/
    .privateHeaderNav ul {
        padding: 0.5em 0.3em;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="privateHeaderNav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h5>LOGO HERE</h5>
          </li>
          <li>
              FOO
          </li>
          <li>
              FOO
          </li>
          <li>
              FOO
          </li>
          <li>
            <button type="button">
              FOO BAR
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for responding. but it show a little bit of improvement. What I did is just remove the button and make `h1` as clickable, although this is not semantically correct but for now turning it into `h1` will do for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Give 'ul' a align-items: flex-start

Comment: i tried that already but also didnt work. that will control the button but not the text.